# How to change the default GCC options by editing files?

Tags: files, gcc

I want to change the default GCC options by editing files. I think it's impossible, but I want to double check.

Comment: Could you possibly give us a bit more context? Are you working with a particular project? Is there a Makefile or does it use CMake or some other build system? Do you know you're dealing with `gcc` in particular, and not `g++`, `clang`, or `clang++` (or some other compiler)?  What are the options you want to change, and what do you want to change them to, and why? In certain contexts, you may change the behavior of the compiler by setting certain environment variables, rather than options, depending on what you want to do. Why do you think you will need to edit a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default options that GCC passes to its subprocesses (the pre-processor, compilers, linker etc.) by writing [spec files](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

```
gcc -dumpspecs
```

will show you the built-in spec file; this can be entirely overridden, by writing a `spec` file in the GCC default directory (which varies depending on your distribution).